# Como reconhecer clique de botão/elemento dentro de uma janela modal?

Tags: jquery, modal

Como reconhecer clique de botão/elemento dentro de uma janela modal?

Tentei o seguinte, sem sucesso:

```
$("#modalEscolha").bind('click', function () {
    if ($("#escolherComp").data('clicked')) {
        alert("Componente!");
    } else if ($('#escolherKIT').data('clicked')) {
        alert("KIT!");
    } else {
        $('#acionamento').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    }
});
```

**Edição**:

Possuo um `input select`, que deve ser setado de acordo com o fechamento do modal ou com o clique dos botões: `escolherComp` ou `escolherKIT`. Caso o usuário feche o modal, ou clicando fora do body, ou no botão close, o `index 0` deverá ser setado, caso contrário, se ocorrer o clique em algum dos botões a opção setada deverá permanecer (nenhuma ação é executada).

Comment: Já tentou usar .on em vez de .bind?

Comment: Olá @DvD, não resolveu.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, sua pergunta seria "_Como setar index 0 no elemento `$('#acionamento')` quando a modal é fechada?_".. Seria isto?

Comment: @DvD, sim e quando nenhum dos botões for clicado.

Comment: Que botões são esses?

Comment: `#escolherComp` e `#escolherKIT` @DvD

Comment: Tente alterando apenas a primeira linha para `$("#modalEscolha, #modalEscolha input").on('hidden.bs.modal click', function () {`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67476/discussion-between-luccasrodrigo-and-dvd).

Comment: Porque não coloca no post o HTML?

Comment: O HTML está "imenso". https://pastebin.com/hETWM3vq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o explicado no chat, tem as seguintes condições:

- 1º ao selecionar o option motorizado é aberto o modal com as duas opções
- 2º se o usuário não clicar em nenhum opção nesse primeiro momento e simplesmente fechar o modal o input select é resetado.
- 3º caso o usuário clique em alguma das opções que está no modal, o option motorizado fica setado e o modal é fechado
- 4º após clicar em alguma das opções no modal é criado um botão "chamado" Trocar, que abre o modal novamente
- 5º a partir desse momento, como o option "Motorizado" já vai estar selecionado, se ele simplesmente fechar o modal novamente NÂO deve ser resetado

**Resultado:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var setarZero="0";
var noBodyFunction="0";
  $('select').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Motorizado") {
        $('#modalEscolhaAc').modal('show');
    }else{
        $("#trocarAc").hide();
        setarZero = ($("#acionamento").prop('selectedIndex'));
    }
  });

  $("#escolherComp, #escolherKIT").on('click', function () {
    $('#acionamento').prop('selectedIndex', 7);
    $("#trocarAc").show();
    setarZero=7;
      if ($(this).attr('id') == 'escolherComp') {
         alert("Componente!");
      } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'escolherKIT') {
         alert("KIT!");
      }
  });
  
  $("#trocarAc").on('click', function () {
    $('#acionamento').prop('selectedIndex', 7);
    noBodyFunction="1";
  });

  if(noBodyFunction!="1"){
    $("body").click(function() {
   target = document.getElementById("modal-footer");
   flag = event.path.some(function(el) {
      return (el == target)
   });
     
   if ((!flag)&&(setarZero !="7")) {
      $('#acionamento').prop('selectedIndex', setarZero);
   }
    });
  }      

});
```

```css
    #escolherKIT{
       background-color: #d3e5f2;
       margin: 3px; padding: 3px;
       height:30px;
       width:200px
    }
    #acionamento{
    width:190px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalEscolhaAc" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
 <!-- Modal content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#000">Acionamento motorizado</h4>
     </div>
     <div id="modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
         <input type="button" name="escolherComp" id="escolherComp" value="Escolher componentes para automação" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
         <input type="button" name="escolherKIT" id="escolherKIT" value="Escolher KIT" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
     </div>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim modal -->
 
 
<select name="acionamento" id="acionamento" required="true" class="form-control">
 <option value="">Selecione um produto</option>
 <option value="Bilateral">Bilateral</option>
 <option value="Central">Central</option>
 <option value="Convencional">Convencional</option>
 <option value="Haste e corda">Haste e corda</option>
 <option value="Invertido">Invertido</option>
 <option value="Lateral">Lateral</option>
 <option value="Motorizado">Motorizado</option>
</select> <input type="button" value="trocar" id="trocarAc" onclick="$('#modalEscolhaAc').modal('show')" style="display: none;"/>
```

Comment: Leo, é o seguinte: sua solução funciona desde que seja considerado o clique apenas nos botões. Caso o usuário não clique em nenhum dos botões, ou seja, simplesmente feche o modal (clicando fora do body ou close) a condição `else {$('#acionamento').prop('selectedIndex',0);}` tem que ser executada. Caso contrário, as outras anteriormente. @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: LeoCaracciolo, podemos continuar essa discussão via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67476/discussion-between-luccasrodrigo-and-dvd)?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo editei a resposta

Comment: Olá Leo, pode acompanhar a discussão via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67476/discussion-between-luccasrodrigo-and-dvd)? Perdão, mas creio que faltou alguns detalhes na pergunta.